How to rollback and return a record in anonymous code block
For my use case I need to perform two operations and rollback if any of them fails. And also return a RECORD, showing which of the operation failed.
I'm trying to do this without using another table to store the operations result. For that reason I'm trying to use anonymous code block with temporary table.
Sadly, I am unable to query the table if there is exception during the query.
-- 0 = operations done successfully
-- 1 = failed to refresh some_view
-- 3 = failed to update some_table
DO $$
    DECLARE
        refresh_error BOOLEAN := FALSE;
        update_error BOOLEAN := FALSE;
        result_code INT := 0;
        result_msg TEXT := '';
    BEGIN
        -- Create a temporary table to store the result
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temporary_tbl;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_tbl(result_code INT, message TEXT);

        BEGIN
            -- Attempting to refresh materialized view
            BEGIN
                REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW public.some_view
                RAISE NOTICE '0 - Successfully refreshed some_view.';
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                    refresh_error := TRUE;
                    result_code := 1;
                    result_msg = 'Error refreshing materialized view: ' || SQLERRM;
                    RAISE NOTICE '1- %s', result_msg;
                    RAISE EXCEPTION USING MESSAGE = result_msg, ERRCODE = result_code::text;
            END;

            -- Attempting to update some_table
            BEGIN
                UPDATE public.some_table
                SET some_date = NOW()
                WHERE some_date IS NULL;
                RAISE NOTICE '0 - some_table update successful.';
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                    update_error := TRUE;
                    result_code := 2;
                    result_msg = 'Error updating some_table: ' || SQLERRM;
                    RAISE NOTICE '2 - %s', result_msg;
                    RAISE EXCEPTION USING MESSAGE = result_msg, ERRCODE = result_code::text;
            END;

        END;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            INSERT INTO temporary_tbl VALUES (result_code, result_msg);

END$$;

-- the temporary table will continue to exist on individual Postgres session
SELECT * FROM temporary_tbl;

What I am trying to do is, use two transaction inside the code block.
The inner one is the actual operations, which if there is any exception, as I am aware it will rollback automatically.
The outer transaction, is catching any errors and inserting into the temporary tabel
It seems that, if there is any rollback in the code block it will also rollback the creating and insertions in the temporary table.
I think this is possible if I create a function, doing something similar, but our Postgres is old version 12.18, which does not have the feature to rollback inside a function I think.

A DO-block is always executed as one single transaction. At least in all current versions of PostgreSQL (2024). You might refer to a stored procedure, that's different. But also supported by all current versions.

If the PostgreSQL version is 9 or later, then tag the post accordingly. If it is an earlier version, then specify which in the body of the post. Stating that it is an old version is inadequate. The behavior you've described could be implemented using DBLINK; however, that approach seems needlessly complex. Have you considered using the DETAIL option with RAISE EXCEPTION to report the specific failed operation? BTW, neither "1" nor "2" are recognized exception conditions: attempting to raise an exception with either will instead raise an exception with SQL state 42704.
